Optimizing User Data Fetching in Next.js: Best Practices and Alternatives
I have a project in Next.js and I am using server actions. However, I am facing a problem: I am fetching user data separately on each page so that I can use it on the respective pages. Is there a way to fetch the user data once and use it across all pages without fetching it on each page?
I understand that one solution might be to use context or tools like **Redux **to fetch the data once and reuse the stored data in other parts. However, I am fetching the data in a server action in a server component, which would then require me to use a client component.
Is there a better way to handle this? Should I consider fetching the data on the client side with some store management, or is there a good alternative?

This is how i solved this problem.
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

    const user = await getCurrentUser() // Hitting tRPC endpoint to get user from DB via sessionId in cookie

    return (
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <TrpcProvider>
                    <UserProvider defaultUser={user}>
                        {children}
                    </UserProvider>
                </TrpcProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}


/ UserProvider
interface UserProviderProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    defaultUser: Public_User_Me_Payload | null | undefined
}

export const UserProvider = ({ children, defaultUser }: UserProviderProps) => {

    const result = trpc.public.user.me.useQuery(undefined, {
        initialData: defaultUser
    })

    const value = {
        user: result.data || defaultUser,
        isLoading: result.isFetching || result.isLoading,
        error: result.error,
        refetch: result.refetch,
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}


Fetching Data in Middleware and Using Custom Headers
You can use a middleware to fetch the user data and attach it to the request headers. This way, the data can be accessed in server actions.
// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getUserData } from '@/services/user';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const userData = await getUserData();
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  
  response.headers.set('x-user-data', JSON.stringify(userData));
  
  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/:path*',
};

Then, in your server components, you can read the user data from the headers:
// app/layout.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const headersList = headers();
  const userData = JSON.parse(headersList.get('x-user-data') || '{}');

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider user={userData}>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


No, this approach is not recommended middleware function is executed on each request so fetching data from the backend or db queries should be avoided you can learn more about this in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_sUsq_y10U
